# How to delete Drop Off library in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

Does anyone know how can I remove a drop off library in Sharepoint Online in Powershell?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not delete `Drop off Library` by default.

But you can set it as hidden I believe. Use Gary Lapointe module - `Lapointe.SharePointOnline.PowerShell.msi` to get `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List` and set `Hidden=True`

```
 Import-Module -Name Lapointe.SharePointOnline.PowerShell 
 Connect-SPOSite -Url $siteCollectionUrl -Credential $spOnlineCredentials
 $dropofflib= Get-SPOList -Web "/" -identity $fullUrlToDropOffLibrary
 $dropofflib.Hidden=$true
 $dropofflib.Update()
```

Download `Lapointe.SharePointOnline.PowerShell.msi` from  https://github.com/glapointe/PowerShell-SPOCmdlets/releases

Reference [How to delete Drop Off library in SharePoint Online](http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/simple-concept-how-to-delete-drop-off.html)

Comment: Can you please specify from where the user can get `Lapointe.SharePointOnline.PowerShell.msi` ? the link provided in the page is already dead link. Without this the PowerShell code is not useful.

Comment: You should get it here i guess https://github.com/glapointe/PowerShell-SPOCmdlets/releases

Answer (score 3):

As far as my knowledge is concern, you cannot delete the `Drop Off Library`. One can delete the `Drop off Library` using Server Side Object Model's `AllowDeletion` property.

But as this is SharePoint Online, as we cannot use SSOM in SharePoint Online, we cannot delete this `Drop off Library`.